# An equality involving matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

In [this](https://youtu.be/DHspIG64CVM?t=31m12s) video, at 31:12, the following equality pops up:

$(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\theta})^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\theta})=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(y_i-\mathbf{x}_i^T\mathbf{\theta})^2$

From the previous slides in the same video, it looks like $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{\theta}$ are column vectors. So in order for the equality to make sense, $\mathbf{x}_i$ should be column vectors (so that their transposes are row vectors, which can be multiplied with the column vector $\mathbf{\theta}$).

I've tried an example, but am not getting that it holds.

$\mathbf{\theta}=\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$\mathbf{y}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$

$\mathbf{X}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&3\\2&4\end{pmatrix}$.

$\mathbf{X\theta}=\begin{pmatrix}5 \\8\end{pmatrix}$

$\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X\theta}=\begin{pmatrix}-4 \\-6\end{pmatrix}$

So the LHS is equal to $-4\times -4+-6\times-6=52$.

\begin{align}(y_1-\mathbf{x}_1^T\mathbf{\theta})^2&=\big(1-\begin{pmatrix}1&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix}\big)^2=9\\
(y_2-\mathbf{x}_2^T\mathbf{\theta})^2&=\big(2-\begin{pmatrix}3&4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix}\big)^2=64
\end{align}

So the RHS equals $73$. Why aren't these values equal?

Comment: I think the $\mathbf{x}_i^T$'s should actually be the rows of $X$.

Comment: So $\mathbf{x}_1$ is actually the transpose of the first row, so that when you take $\mathbf{x}_1^T$ you get the first row? Doesn't look like the most natural notation to me, but I guess I'll get used to it

Comment: No, it's not natural notation - don't get used to it. Natural notation is to have $\mathbf{x}_i$ denote a column vector. I think the author has chosen this odd use of notation to ensure the reader (watcher) is aware that the object being considered is a transposed column vector of some sort ... maybe ... I'm just guessing really ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, and let $\theta \in K^n$ and $y \in K^m$ (we regard the elements of $K^k$ as column vectors). For $1 \leq i \leq m$ let $x_i$ denote the $i$-th row of $X$ (in particular $x_i$ is a row vector and thus $x_i^T \in K^n$). For $v,w \in K^n$ let
$$
 \langle v,w \rangle
= \sum_{i=1}^n v_i w_i
= v_i^T w_i.
$$

For all $1 \leq i \leq m$ we have
$$
 (X \theta)_i
 = \sum_{j=1}^n X_{ij} \theta_j
 = \sum_{j=1}^n (x_i)^T_j \theta_j
 = \langle x_i^T, \theta \rangle,
$$
and therefore
$$
 (y - X \theta)_i
= y_i - (X \theta)_i
= y_i - \langle x_i^T, \theta \rangle,
$$
as well as
$$
 a^T a = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2
 \quad\text{for every $a \in K^m$}.
$$
Putting this together we have
$$
 (y - X \theta)^T (y - X \theta)
 = \sum_{i=1}^n (y - X \theta)_i^2
 = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \langle x_i^T, \theta \rangle)^2.
$$

I guess your confusion comes from the fact that instead of $\langle v,w \rangle$ your formule writes $vw$, leading you to belive that $x_i^T$ must be row vector, while it really is a column vector (i.e. $x_i$ is, as defined above, the $i$-th row of $X$ and *not* the $i$-th column).

Regarding your calculation, you now have to swap two elements:

\begin{align*}
 (y_1 - \langle \mathbf{x}_1^T, \mathbf{\theta} \rangle)^2
 &=\left(
  1-
  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \color{red}{3}\end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
 \right)^2
 = 16\\
 (y_2 - \langle \mathbf{x}_2^T,  \mathbf{\theta} \rangle)^2
 &=\left(
  2-
  \begin{pmatrix} \color{red}{2} & 4 \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
 \right)^2
 =36.
\end{align*}

Comment: But wouldn't (1 3) be a row vector, rather than a column vector?

Comment: I didn’t make it clear enough to distinguish between matrix multiplication and scalar multiplication. I edited my answer and introduced a seperate (standard) notation for the scalar product.